# How to Repeat All Labels in PIVOT Table- Apache POI

Tags: javascript, java, apache-poi, pivot-table

How to achieve the Repeat All items in Pivot table as per below screen shot and also need to know how we can get that drop down icon across all columns. now drop down icon showing only at the first column.
Is Repeat All Items is achievable in Apache POI?.

below is the code.

Output which i am getting:

[image]

output which i need:

[image]

```
 public class TestPivotTable
 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    String[][] data = new String[][]{{"AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EEE","FFF","GGG","HHH"}, 
 {"TOM","DUMMY","VAL","1001683","Description1","27/04/2017","CAT","7,80,936.58"},
        {"TOM","DUMMY","VAL","1001695","Description2","27/04/2017","CAT","136.28"},
        {"HARRY","DUMMY1","VAL1","1001692","Description3","03/05/2017","CAT1","191468.21"},
        {"HARRY","DUMMY1","VAL1","1001698","Description4","04/05/2017","CAT1","10.11"}};

    XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("data");
    XSSFSheet pivot = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("summary");
    for(String[] dataRow : data){
        XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows());
        for(String dataCell : dataRow){
            XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells());
            cell.setCellValue(dataCell);
        }
    }
    XSSFTable table = sheet.createTable();    
    CTTable cttable = table.getCTTable();
    table.setDisplayName("table");
    cttable.setRef("A1:D4");
    cttable.setId(1);

    CTTableColumns columns = cttable.addNewTableColumns();
    columns.setCount(3);

    int g = 1;
    for (String colName : data[0]){
        CTTableColumn column = columns.addNewTableColumn();
        column.setId(++g);
        column.setName(colName);      
    }
  AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference("A1:H"+ (sheet.getLastRowNum() + 
  1),SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
  FileOutputStream fileOut=null;
  try {
    XSSFPivotTable pivotTable =  pivot.createPivotTable(areaReference, new CellReference("A1"), 
  sheet);

    pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setRowHeaderCaption("AAA");

    List<Integer> iterList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    iterList.add(0);
    iterList.add(1);
    iterList.add(2);
    iterList.add(3);
    iterList.add(4);
    iterList.add(5);
    iterList.add(6);

    for (Integer j : iterList) {

        pivotTable.addRowLabel(j);
        TreeSet<String> uniqueItems = new java.util.TreeSet<String>();
        for (int r = areaReference.getFirstCell().getRow()+1; r < 
   areaReference.getLastCell().getRow()+1; r++) {
            uniqueItems.add(sheet.getRow(r).getCell(j).toString());
        }
        System.out.println(uniqueItems);
        CTPivotField ctPivotField = 
   pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(j);
        int i = 0;
        for (String item : uniqueItems) {
            ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).unsetT();
            ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).setX((long)i);


pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().
 getCacheFieldArray(j)
            .getSharedItems().addNewS().setV(item);
            i++;
        }
       // ctPivotField.setAutoShow(false);
        ctPivotField.setDefaultSubtotal(false);
         ctPivotField.setOutline(false);
       // ctPivotField.setCompact(false);
       // ctPivotField.setSubtotalTop(true);
        if (ctPivotField.getDefaultSubtotal()) i++; 
        for (int k = ctPivotField.getItems().getItemList().size()-1; k >= i; k--) {
            ctPivotField.getItems().removeItem(k);
        }
        ctPivotField.getItems().setCount(i);

    }

    System.out.println("----end---");

    pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 7, "SUM");

    fileOut = new FileOutputStream("newoutputfile.xlsx");
    wb.write(fileOut);
}catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Exception While Creating Pivot Table"+e);
}finally {
    fileOut.close();
    wb.close();
}

}
```

}

Comment: Hi All, Can we achieve the "Repeat All Items Label" from apache POI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Repeat All Items Label" setting for pivot tables was implemented after the `Office Open XML` was published. That's why it is not part of it. It uses special extended `XML` from name space `x14`. But `apache poi` only provides `Office Open XML`.

So if we want using extended `XML` from name space `x14`, we need doing that on low `XML` level.

First we need setting updated pivot table version to 6 instead of 3.

Then we need set `<x14:pivotField fillDownLabels="1"/>` for each `CTPivotField`. This is the "Repeat All Items Label" setting.

Complete example which extends your showed code:

```
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.List;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.*;

public class TestPivotTable {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Object[][] data = new Object[][]{
   {"AAA","BBB","CCC","DDD","EEE","FFF","GGG","HHH"}, 
   {"TOM","DUMMY","VAL","1001683","Description1","27/04/2017","CAT",780936.58},
   {"TOM","DUMMY","VAL","1001695","Description2","27/04/2017","CAT",136.28},
   {"HARRY","DUMMY1","VAL1","1001692","Description3","03/05/2017","CAT1",191468.21},
   {"HARRY","DUMMY1","VAL1","1001698","Description4","04/05/2017","CAT1",10.11}
  };

  XSSFSheet sheet = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("data");
  XSSFSheet pivot = (XSSFSheet) wb.createSheet("summary");
  for(Object[] dataRow : data){
   XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows());
   for(Object dataCell : dataRow){
    XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells());
    if (dataCell instanceof String) {
     cell.setCellValue((String)dataCell);
    } else if (dataCell instanceof Double) {
     cell.setCellValue((Double)dataCell);
    }
   }
  }

  AreaReference areaReference = new AreaReference("A1:H"+ (sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1), SpreadsheetVersion.EXCEL2007);
  XSSFPivotTable pivotTable =  pivot.createPivotTable(areaReference, new CellReference("A1"), sheet);
  pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setRowHeaderCaption("AAA");

  List<Integer> iterList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  iterList.add(0);
  iterList.add(1);
  iterList.add(2);
  iterList.add(3);
  iterList.add(4);
  iterList.add(5);
  iterList.add(6);

  //set updated pivot table version to 6
  //necessary to make extended pivot table setting available
  pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().setUpdatedVersion((short)6); 

  for (Integer j : iterList) {

   //create row label - apache poi creates as much fields for each as rows are in the pivot table data range
   pivotTable.addRowLabel(j);

   //determine unique labels in column j
   TreeSet<String> uniqueItems = new java.util.TreeSet<String>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
   for (int r = areaReference.getFirstCell().getRow()+1; r < areaReference.getLastCell().getRow()+1; r++) {
    uniqueItems.add(sheet.getRow(r).getCell(j).getStringCellValue());
   }
   System.out.println(uniqueItems);
   
   //build pivot table and cache
   CTPivotField ctPivotField = pivotTable.getCTPivotTableDefinition().getPivotFields().getPivotFieldArray(j);
   int i = 0;
   for (String item : uniqueItems) {
    //take the items as numbered items: <item x="0"/><item x="1"/>
    ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).unsetT();
    ctPivotField.getItems().getItemArray(i).setX((long)i);
    //build a cache definition which has shared elements for those items 
    //<sharedItems><s v="TOM"/><s v="HARRY"/></sharedItems>
    pivotTable.getPivotCacheDefinition().getCTPivotCacheDefinition().getCacheFields().getCacheFieldArray(j)
     .getSharedItems().addNewS().setV(item);
    i++;
   }

   //ctPivotField.setAutoShow(false);
   ctPivotField.setDefaultSubtotal(false);
   //ctPivotField.setSubtotalTop(false);
   //ctPivotField.setSubtotalCaption(null);
   //ctPivotField.setCompact(false);
   ctPivotField.setOutline(false);

   //remove further items
   if (ctPivotField.getDefaultSubtotal()) i++; //let one default item be if there shall be subtotals
   for (int k = ctPivotField.getItems().getItemList().size()-1; k >= i; k--) {
    ctPivotField.getItems().removeItem(k);
   }
   ctPivotField.getItems().setCount(i);

   //set <x14:pivotField fillDownLabels="1"/> for each CTPivotField
   //this is the "Repeat All Items Label" setting
   CTExtensionList extList = ctPivotField.addNewExtLst();
   CTExtension ext = extList.addNewExt();
   String extXML = 
      "<x14:pivotField"
    + " xmlns:x14=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/spreadsheetml/2009/9/main\""
    + " fillDownLabels=\"1\"/>";
   org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject xlmObject = org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject.Factory.parse(extXML);
   ext.set(xlmObject);
   ext.setUri("{2946ED86-A175-432a-8AC1-64E0C546D7DE}");  
   
  }

  System.out.println("----end---");

  pivotTable.addColumnLabel(DataConsolidateFunction.SUM, 7, "SUM");

  FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("newoutputfile.xlsx");
  wb.write(fileOut);
  fileOut.close();
  wb.close();
 }
}
```

Note: I have removed the `XSSFTable` creation from your code since it is not necessary and is done wrong and leads to a corrupted `Excel` file if done as you have done it.

Comment: Thank you So Much Axel Richter, Its working as expected!!!. Thanks for nice explanation for the fix. its really helps me a lot.